# Is Desktop Manager compiled with kernel in iso distribution files

Tags: linux, compiling, small-distribution

I'm trying to see the process of redistributing a linux distribution. I was wondering if all the components are compiled with the kernel or kernel is seperated from components like is Desktop Manager compiled with kernel or i should place the DM packages in the iso file and the installer has to install it after the kernel or maybe other ways! Sorry im new in this but i have experience in compiling, developing and mid level programming and im willing to do it at least in the minimal way. I appreciate any explanation, suggestions, guidance any thing that can help to get started

Comment: The linux kernel is separate from the desktop manager and other application software.

Comment: So how does installer installs them? does installer installs grub seperated too? @sudodus

Comment: You should start with Linux From Scratch: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org

Comment: This is a very general question, and a complete answer could be very long. One way to learn is to do the tasks manually with [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) // ninja'd by Emmanuel Rosa ;-)

Comment: That's a good guid guys thank you, lets try to make the long answere cuz many ppl have the question and they would expect to get the answere here, just like me....i would try and i will share the results here @sudodus

Comment: Good luck with Linux From Scratch and you are welcome to share your results here :-)